# Who perform deadlock prevention, avoidance and check and recovery?

Tags: concurrency, operating-systems

In OS books (e.g. Operating System Concepts), there are three strategies of dealing with deadlock between processes or threads:

- prevent,
- avoid, and
- check and recovery.

Who performs the strategies?

- is it always an entity, different from the processes or threads being considered as candidates of deadlock? For example, an OS?
- when writing a concurrent application program  with multiple processes or threads, is there a main process or main thread in charge of dealing with (prevent, avoid, check and recover) deadlock between the other processes or threads?

Is it correct that

- the last two strategies (avoidance, and checking and recovery) seem to be performed only by OS or some middleware (in a distributed system), not by an application program?
- deadlock prevention can be performed by OS or middleware (e.g. preemption, no hold and wait), or by an application program (e.g. all processes or threads request resources in the same order, e.g. request two mutex locks in the same order)?

or does an OS book assume that all three strategies are performed by OS?

Comment: Hello Tim, have you considered asking these questions at https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/ ? These are basically questions regarding lack of clarity in CS textbooks, and the work of clarifying those texts are of primary interest to CS educators. Meanwhile, most software programming practitioners either took those answers to be obvious (or, having been internalized from years ago), or that they don't matter at all to their everyday roles. I don't mean to discourage, but I can see that receiving downvotes can be discouraging.

Comment: Do you have a reference for those strategies? I tried to search for it, and it appears that it is 1. Prevent and avoid. and 2. Check and recover.

Comment: (1 of 2 - Very generally speaking) Deadlock is a general phenomenon that can occur between two or more actors with the result that, eventually, some or all of the actors are unable to make any forward progress forever. As a general phenomenon, it can appear in many kinds of systems and across many levels of abstractions. It is not even limited to computer systems, e.g. one could possibly construct examples where it happens in legal systems, political systems, or administrative organizations.

Comment: (2 of 2 - Thinking reflectively) When the textbook talks about deadlock prevention, it is talking about responsibilities of programmers and system designers in working together to prevent either the occurrence of deadlocks or to prevent the consequences of an actual deadlock from harming overall system stability. It is assumed that everyone sincerely work toward that goal. It is assumed that humans may make errors (programming mistakes, design defects, or inherent limitations) that make deadlocks possible.

Comment: There is no general way of proving that a given binary program contains a deadlock (or, conclusively not containing any possible deadlocks), without the binary program actually executing and an actual deadlock occurring. Thus, the OS cannot interject unless it actually observes that the program has already entered into a deadlock.

Comment: Whether the OS can "understand" what's happening with a process may depend on whether the process uses OS-provided synchronization primitives (e.g. mutexes, etc). If a process uses its own constructs for synchronization (e.g. shared memory, atomic memory operations, spin wait), the OS can only see that the process appears to execute a very tight loop, but will not have conclusive evidence that the process is in a state of being deadlocked.

Comment: A process that has deadlocked means that the threads of that process have collectively refused to make any progress. Why they refuse to make progress is not something apparent to the OS at all - a human, such as a reverse engineerer, will have to look at the code in order to reason about that. In many cases, programs are written to keep spinning until a condition is met. When such programs encounter a deadlock, it is possible that, even if the OS interjects and forces one of the threads to keep executing (e.g. allowing it to enter or exit a critical section or passing a barrier) ...

Comment: ..., that the program's code sees that its wait criteria has not been met, and then immediately loops back to the lock acquisition. In other words, even if the OS forcibly "wakes" a thread, the thread may simply goes back into a "wait" immediately.

Comment: Thus, it can be seen that, ultimately, the burden of careful design and coding for preventing a deadlock, mostly lies on the designers and programmers of that application. The roles for an OS to rescue an application process is limited.

Comment: If the deadlock occurred because threads are calling OS routines and in turn the synchronization needs within those OS routines caused that deadlock, the OS may decide that one or more those OS routine calls may need to fail (be aborted). The OS can simply cause one or more OS routine calls to return a failure code. In this case, it is the responsibility of the application process to implement proper error-handling and react gracefully when it happens. The possibility that a certain OS routine may fail if it cannot acquire a certain resource or a lock needs to be documented.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock prevention is something you deal with at the application level. Most operating systems are not able to check whether there is a potential deadlock in a program. If you are to create a multithreaded program that makes use of mutex locks, you would have to prevent the potential deadlocks yourself, since, as I said, the operating system does not know that a deadlock can happen. The operating system you executes the instructions in your program. Of course, one can implement some kind of deadlock detection feature in the operating system that checks for deadlock before executing it.

On the other hand, checking and recovery is usually done by the operating system. As an example, when Blue Screen of Death happens on a Windows machine, it is typically because of a deadlock in a running process. In this case, the operating system has checked for deadlock and will try to recover from it. The aggressive approach is to restart the computer (Blue Screen of Death).

Regarding deadlock avoidance, this is something that is done before the deadlock happens. Deadlocks can be avoided by the scheduler in the operating system if we are on a machine with multiple processors. In this case, we can schedule the processes to run on the different processors depending on how they acquire the locks.